# React / Axios: Unable to set state on two objects at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

My entire function is here below:

```js
  initializeData = () => {
    const promise1 = axios.get(
      "/workflow/boards/" + this.state.boardId + ".json"
    );
    const promise2 = axios.get("/workflow/boardIds.json");
    Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);

        // this.setState(response[0].data); //This works fine
        // this.setState({ boardIds: response[1].data }); //This works fine
        this.setState(response[0].data, {boardIds: response[1].data}); //This throws error
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error returned on getColumns: " + error);
      });
  };
```

I can set the state of each promise individually, but when I attempt the last setState I get this error:

**Error: Invalid argument passed as callback. Expected a function. Instead received: [object Object]**

It feels like I should be able to accomplish this without having the set state twice, but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The parameters to `setState` must either be an object or an object with a callback function. You likely mean `setState({ ...response[0].data, boardIds: response[1].data })`

Comment: show your initial state declaration

Comment: @EugenSunic I don't think that will help; the error has been diagnosed and explained already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of setState is `(updater, [callback])` - the second parameter is a function that runs after the state has been updated. You're currently passing two objects, hence the error about the second parameter.

Combine both updates into a single object:

```js
this.setState({...response[0].data, boardIds: response[1].data});
```

Comment: It takes multiple arguments, just not two objects.

Comment: Well shoot, that was easy! Thanks so much!!